# Эффект свечения при наведении на иконки

Tags: css, hover

Как можно сделать неоновый hover эффект на иконки соц.-сетей?

Уже пробовал `box-shadow: 0 0 20px #......;`, при наведении создаётся неоновый квадрат, а мне нужно, чтобы светилась сама иконка, а не область вокруг неё.

Comment: Можете использовать fontawesome иконки и уже при наведении менять их цвет.

Comment: @ValeraKononenko иконки как раз с fontawesome, при наведении цвет меняется, но мне нужен именно эффект свечения

Answer (score 4):

Так как [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) - это шрифтовые иконки, следовательно к ним нужно применять не [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), а [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow).

```css
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css');

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: #111;
}

.icon-hover-neon > i {
  font-size: calc(50vw / 3);
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-hover-neon > i:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

.icon-hover-neon > i:hover {
  text-shadow:
    0 0 2vw rgba(255,255,255,.5),
    0 0 5vw #09f;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-hover-neon">
  <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```
.social-icon-link:hover .social-icon {
    fill: var(--text-white-color);
```

задает ховер на иконку